# Is there any CRM based on an modern Java EE Stack (Spring/EJB, JPA)?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jakarta-ee, crm

I have to build a special customized Customer Relation Ship Managment tool. There are only basic requirements (manage customers, add notes for them, attach an email,…) for the CMR, except the one, which is about integration of a specific application to store and get some data.

So I am looking for an Open Source CRM where I can add this specific stuff, because I do not want to reinvent the weel and implement the next CRM by my own. So I am looking for an **Web Based, Open Source CRM written in Java, that is based on a modern Java Web Stack**. I would prefer something that is **based on Spring (or EJB 3.1) and JPA**. Of course more important than the used technologies is the **quality of the code** (and documentation).

After looking around for some hours I did not find any project that fit my needs. So I ask, **can anybody recommend a CRM that matches my needs, or should I really implement it completely by my own?**

Comment: Hi Ralph, finally what crm did you use. I am also looking for a good Spring/Hibernate(JPA) based CRM.

Comment: @HemantNagpal: we implemented our own

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at?:

- JFire: https://www.jfire.org/modules/content/
- openCRX: http://www.opencrx.org/
- openbravo: http://www.openbravo.com/

Comment: Thanks, I don't know openbravo. Did you ever used one of them? And did you get openCRX compiling and running?

Comment: No, I didn't use any of them. Sorry :/

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [Apache OFbiz](http://ofbiz.apache.org/) ? They implemented a lot of stuff including customer management.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a second look on it, but at the first glance it looks much to heavy weight for my needs. - Do you have any experience how much it can be tailored down to some minimal stuff?

Comment: No, I did not work with it. From my experience, projects under Apache hood are usually of good quality, that's why I suggested it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with [opentaps](http://www.opentaps.org/), but it looks quite nice.

Comment: Did you find the source code (or some kind of architeture desciption) somewhere?

Comment: Source code is here: [link](http://gitorious.org/opentaps) or here: [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opentaps/)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend Opentaps CRMSFA. I had an experience of 7 months. I hope it might be a best solution for you, using this you can perform :

1. Lead management ( Lead Content management, Add notes etc)
2. Opportunity management
3. Case Management
4. Campaign management
5. Email Communication ( Java mail Client)
6. Log emails, Calls
7. Dash Board reporting
8. PDF, HTML, XLS Reporting
9. Calender Management
10. Team management etc

But it is not a ready made baby, you should understand the work-flow in order to implement you business logic.

Comment: But does Opentabs satisfy the more technical needs to: Spring/EJB 3.1, JPA, good code?